# Trying to write to a external json file using fs and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, node.js-fs

I'm trying to write an object to a JSON, when passing the data through to the server I keep receiving this error and I cannot seem to find a solution to fix it...

Here is my code

```js
APP.post('/api', (req, res) => {
    
    const data = req.body;
    console.log(data);

    try {
        fs.writeFileSync(PATH, data);
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }

    res.send("Updated");
});
```

The object looks like the following i.e. `req.body`

```json
{
  name: '',
  currentStats: {
    stat: 0,

  },
  trackStats: { history: 0 }
}
```

The error in question

`TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received an instance of Object`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fs.writeFileSync writes data in binary format, and it expects a buffer or a string as the second argument. Thus you need to convert your JavaScript object to a JSON string using JSON.stringify()

fs.writeFileSync(PATH,JSON.stringify(data));

Comment: Oh yes it seems to work now, do you know how I would then not overwrite the json?

Comment: İf i got your mean, it's possible fs.appendFileSync(PATH, JSON.stringify(data)) like that